# Difference between [string]::Format and -f, and Array vs split operator

Tags: powershell

I have written this code to exhibit a difference in the method of formatting strings:

### Example using Split

```
$arr = 'that,way'

$arr = $arr -split ","

$arr.GetType()
$arr.Count

try {
$rundmc = [string]::format("It's like {0} and that's the {1} it is",$arr)
}
catch {
    Write-Host "String::format failed"
    $rundmc = "It's like {0} and that's the {1} it is" -f $arr
}
Write-Host $rundmc
```

### Example defining the input array as an actual array

```
$arr2 = @('that','way')

$arr2.GetType()
$arr2.Count

try {
$rundmc = [string]::format("It's like {0} and that's the {1} it is",$arr2)
}
catch {
    Write-Host "String::format failed"
    $rundmc = "It's like {0} and that's the {1} it is" -f $arr2
}
Write-Host $rundmc
```

In the first half, the `try` block fails and moves onto the second version of the command which works.

What is the difference between `[string]::Format` and the `-f` operator in powershell?

The first version of the command fails:

```
$rundmc = [string]::format("It's like {0} and that's the {1} it is",$arr)
Exception calling "Format" with "2" argument(s): "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."
At line:1 char:1
+ $rundmc = [string]::format("It's like {0} and that's the {1} it is",$ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

But `-f` works. To me they both look fairly equivalent.

### Difference between the two data types:

#### Split

Get Type

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                               
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array
```

Count

```
2
```

#### Array

Get Type

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                               
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Count

```
2
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using a tabstop inside your string? Try to simply define your array like this: `$arr = 'that','way'`. This way the code in your try block works just as exprected. ... at least for me.

Comment: Ah yes, so perhaps it's more of a question about the behaviour of `split`

Comment: Hmmm ... yes and no. If you use a tab stop you can split on the tab stop. But most editors insert 4 spaces instead of a real tab stop if you hit the tab key.

Comment: You could use something like this: `[string]::format("It's like {0} and that's the {1} it is",$($arr))`

Comment: See updated question, I've replaced it with a comma. Sorry, this isn't really a question about how to do something, it's more about how Powershell is doing stuff. I've solved the problem, I'm just more curious about what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the overloads for `[string]::Format`:

> ```
> OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                    
> -------------------                                                                                                    
> static string Format(string format, System.Object arg0)                                                                
> static string Format(string format, System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1)                                            
> static string Format(string format, System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1, System.Object arg2)                        
> static string Format(string format, Params System.Object[] args)                                                       
> static string Format(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, System.Object arg0)                               
> static string Format(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1)           
> static string Format(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1,           
> System.Object arg2)                                                                                                    
> static string Format(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, Params System.Object[] args)
> ```

You can see the one you are trying to use is this one:

[`static string Format(string format, Params System.Object[] args)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___)

Note that it is expecting its values an object array.

When you use the `-split` operator, as you've seen, the result is a `[String[]]`, not an `[Object[]]`.

```
$arr = 'that,way'
$arr = $arr -split ","
$arr.GetType()
$arr -is [Object[]] # false
```

Why doesn't it get coerced into an `[Object[]]` even though it could be?

Because of this overload:

`static string Format(string format, System.Object arg0)`

`$arr -isnot [Object[]]` however `$arr -is [Object]`, so this overload matches exactly.

Unfortunately since your format string contains 2 replacements, and you called an overload that only supplies 1, you get this error.

If you had done `[String]::Format('Just 1: {0}', $arr)` your call would be successful (but the result would be `Just 1: System.String[]` because of the `.ToString()` method being called on the argument).

Since most arrays in PowerShell end up as `[Object[]]`, it works when defining a literal array, or if your array was assigned as the output of a pipeline.

As an example, you can still use your `[String[]]` version of `$arr` if you do any of the following:

```
[String]::Format('{0}~{1}', $($arr))
[String]::Format('{0}~{1}', ([Object[]]$arr))
[String]::Format('{0}~{1}', ($arr -as [Object[]]))
[String]::Format('{0}~{1}', ($arr|%{$_}))
```

### What about the `-f` operator?

[Let's look at the source code for it](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c1c5344a8897262433141ecbc13bb06ac2c4bbef/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Operations/StringOps.cs#L64).

The very first thing it does is try to convert its argument into an `object[]`:

```cs
object[] formatArgsArray = formatArgs as object[];
```

Comment: Wonderfully comprehensive answer, could I just ask how to get the Overload Definitions? Is there a method within Powershell itself (e.g. part of `Get-Help`?

Comment: @mjsqu sure, in PowerShell you can just invoke the name of the method, but without parentheses: `[String]::Format` and it will give you the list. In ISE the intellisense will also show you, but it disappears after a few seconds (you can bring it up again with `CTRL [SPACE]`)